# How to efficiently store the LatLng route path coming from android application

Tags: android, spring, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ehcache

I'm working on an android app which keeps track of a vehicle's location and sends a LatLng point every second to another spring webapp after click of a button "Start vehicle". 
I need to store this location so as to be rendered in google maps to show live location of the vehicle on the map. It is working fine but, I have to store all the obtained points so as to show a complete route traversed when the driver clicks "Stop vehicle" from the app.

I've applied the following strategies but all seem to be inefficient and too resource consuming:

- Store the location in a list at the server side when each current location request arrives and preserve that in servletContext. Keep on updating the list with every point received. Problem: For a journey of even around 1 hour, too many points are received and they make a very big list consuming loads of memory. If server shuts down or something crashes, the servletContext is gone and so is the whole data.
- Store the location in a table row in DB (using PostgreSQL). Problem: When should the entry be persisted in DB? and then making DB transactions + consuming that much of Database space? Costly, right?
- Do not store all the locations at server side, just keep the current one for live maps. Rather preserve the locations list at android app side and send that to server when the driver chooses to stop the vehicle. Problem: Sounds fair from the server's side, but would the android phone be able to handle that very same big list and then send that in a call to the server?
- Using hibernate and ehcache. Should i consider that?

I am stuck into this on how to do this efficiently by hogging least amount of resources and ofcourse reducing production server costs.

Any help would be appreciated for both Android, server and the whole approach altogether:)

Comment: *"Using hibernate and ehcache"* ... it is not relevant for your current problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce your data to meaningful amounts:

- Rather than sending data on a fixed time-interval, watch for location changes.
- Make the location change threshold speed-dependent; at highway speeds, one mile might be accurate enough, whereas in city driving, you might want a resolution down to 100 yards.
- Collect your data points in the android app, and have it interpolate it. If you drive a straight line between two cities, there's no reason to report all the hundreds of intermediate points, but rather just the end points.

Comment: thanks @323go. And how could that be implemented? Does that mean I need to use the google maps Road API for speed limits and snap-to-road feature? I looked into it, it is limited to a 100 points in 1 request and is ofcourse a paid one.

Comment: You don't need any services to determine speed -- `hasSpeed()` and `getSpeed()` are your friends. You don't need to snap to road... Just use linear regression between arbitrary points until the deviation is low enough. Might take a bit of tinkering.